# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException after server has not been accessed for hours

Tags: mysql, hibernate

There is a Grails2.2/Hibernate/Tomcat7/MySQL5.5 web server. After none web client has requested it for hours, the first request to it fails as follows. (In fact, it happens every morning.) Any sequential requests are handled correctly.

I instructed MySQL driver to `?autoReconnect=true` but it didn't help.

A rollback could be noticed below but I do not call it directly from my code. Instead it happens implicitly when trying to persist an object after the long pause.

Any idea to cure that?

```
Error 500: Executing action [actionName] of controller [MyController] caused exception: Runtime error executing action
Servlet: grails
URI: /appname/grails/appName/actionName.dispatch
Exception Message: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown. 
Caused by: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown. 
Class: MyController 
At Line: [139] 
Code Snippet:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4808)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.rollback(DelegatingConnection.java:368)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.rollback(PoolingDataSource.java:323)
    at MyController.logRequest(...)
    ...
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Tomcat's context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/JNDI_NAME" auth="Container"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true"
 username="xxx" password="xxx" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
 removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"
 maxWait="-1"/>
```

Comment: when your application is Idle for more than 8 hours then this problem is happening ? .is it ?can you post your hibernate.cfg.xml configuration

Comment: Yes, it happens after a night! I'll try to find that xml and add it to the question. 10x

Comment: The file is missed both from my project and war.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following c3po configuration to your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. That should help; see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/).

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

c3p0 is not used in my application so I end up with telling my data source to validate db connection first:

```
<Resource ...
   validationQuery="SELECT 1"
   testOnBorrow="true"/>
```